# How do files within an archive (such as a game) reference an offset in another file in the same archive?

Tags: file

I'm currently attempting to reverse engineer the files of a game in order to make a database of all of the weapons/armor pieces/recipes etc. in that game.

Basically the game stores everything in a single DAT file, and I've been able to find the part of the DAT where all of the string archives (.strs files) are stored.

For example, in 931092.strs you might have:

Offset 2B5E: Ring of Giant Slaying, Offset 375E: Bandit's Insignia

And that kind of thing.

However, the stats on the items (like +100 Strength, +50 Stamina etc.) are elsewhere in the DAT (I don't yet know where).

Presumably, there is some kind of index somewhere in the DAT that says "item id 90151, name is stored here: [file name, offset], stats are stored here: [file name, offset], icon is stored here..." etc.

My question is, since I have the exact location of the item names (i.e. "Sword of Berserking" is at x offset in example101.strs), how could I use this data to figure out where in the DAT the stats are being kept?

Thanks in advance for any help anybody can provide.